# How do I focus on file navigation in open / save dialog boxes?

Tags: keyboard, dialog

When the dialog opens, it is focused on file navigation. After pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>, the search box is highlighted. But how do I get back to file navigation with the keyboard? I used to be able to just <kbd>tab</kbd> back, but that seems to have stopped working.

I’m **not** interested in “Full Keyboard Access”.

[image: Open Dialog Box]

macOS 10.14

Comment: Did you try using Shift + Tab keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @NimeshNeema: Shift + Tab does not work.